# Dynamically changing routes using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ui-router

I have bunch of JSON models in my project and I need to show different models depends on user's actions.

Here is Angular router code:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      }).when('/doc/:section, {
        templateUrl: 'views/doc.html',
        controller: 'DocCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

And here is DocCtrl.js file:

```
app.controller('DocCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'JSONModelsService',
    function ($scope, $http, JSONModelsService) {

        var formData = {};

        $scope.group = {};
        $scope.sections = [];

        JSONModelsService.get([section])
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $scope.group = response.data.groups[0];

                $scope.sections = $scope.group.sections;
            });

    }]);
```

I basically need to make `section` dynamic so I can show different models in my views. However, I'm confused how I can do it. I just have a folder called `JSONModels` with multiple json files.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are aiming at replacing the `[section]` part of your code with an actual section identifier?

When a user visits your `/doc/:section` route, e.g. `/doc/my-doc` you can access the `:section` part by injecting the `$routeParams` service into your controller.

```js
app.controller('DocCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'JSONModelsService',
    function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, JSONModelsService) {
  ...
```

Using the `$routeParams` service, you have access to your route parameters. So you can simple access the `:section` parameter, by reading it off `$routeParams.section`.

A full example (of what I think you're trying to achieve):

```js
app.controller('DocCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'JSONModelsService',
function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, JSONModelsService) {

    var formData = {};

    $scope.group = {};
    $scope.sections = [];

    JSONModelsService.get([$routeParams.section])
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.group = response.data.groups[0];

            $scope.sections = $scope.group.sections;
        });

}]);
```

If you would like to know more, take a look at step 7 of the angular tutorial: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07